# How can the intercept of a logistic regression be more than 1?

Tags: regression, logistic

I have a model with one predictor and 1 control variable. The dependent variable is binary, either 0 or 1.

But the intercept is around 2.5? How is this possible? I thought the logistic regression would limit the function between 0 and 1?

Comment: The intercept is for the *logit* of the probability, not the probability itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logit scale goes from minus infinity to infinity. So there is nothing anomalous with it. A logit value approaching plus infinity back transforms to a probability approaching 1. And a logit value approaching minus infinity corresponds to a probability approaching zero. A logit value of zero corresponds to a probability of 0.5

Comment: Specifically, $\frac{1}{1+\exp(-2.5)}\approx 0.92$.

Comment: So, fx an intercept value of 2 = log-odds of 2 if x = 0?

Comment: Yes, basically. Though it does depend on how the factor is coded. If you are using R, the intercept would be the log odds at x=0 at the first level of the factor.